# MS Access: Make tables

Tags: ms-access

For larger tables, running a maketable can sometimes take tens of minutes. Is there any way to speed the process up? I'm only vaguely aware of indexes but I don't know if they are relevant here for maketable speedup.

Comment: A maketable just makes a copy of an existing table?  I don't see how an index could help with that.  Seems like more likely a hard disk or network related problem (defragment)?  Or maybe it's just a really really big table?

Comment: @dbaseman A make table query does not just copy an existing table, it can pull data from several tables, so indexes are relevant. John, you should post the SQL of the query. Not only do you need relevant indexes, you also need to make sure that your query is structired in such a way as to take advantage of those indexes.

Comment: @Remou It's more of a general question. Let's say it's just joining two tables together by linking together customer ID, pulling in other side-fields like Name, Region, and Revenue or something.

Comment: In a general way, indexes can affect the speed of any query.

Comment: Work in improving the speed of the query that builds the table. This is where to utilize indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are used to speed up the joining of multiple tables.  They won't help you build a table faster unless that table is being built from data pulled in by a query.  If that's the case, it's the QUERY that's taking so long to build and you should definitely consider indexing the related tables.